# How to create api endpoint after created the docker container on ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I've created a docker container for my server on ec2 using nodejs.
I wonder what is the next step I should do if I want to create an rest API endpoint for public access.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

WORKDIR /server

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . . 

EXPOSE 3030

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  test-db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=true
      - MYSQL_USER=admin
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=12345
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=test
    volumes:
      - ./db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
  test-web:
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=local
      #- DEBUG=*
      - PORT=3030
    build: .
    command: >
      ./wait-for-db-redis.sh test-db npm run dev
    volumes:
      - ./:/server
    ports:
      - "3030:3030"
    depends_on:
      - test-db
```

Comment: You mean API Gateway endpoint?

Comment: not necessarily API Gateway. I am not sure what choices do I have.

Comment: Can you provide more info on what is your docker? What kind of app is it? Is it just rest API? There are many posibilities.

Comment: @Marcin updated

Comment: Does it work as expected on port 3030? If yes, then what's wrong with it, and why do you want to add anything in-front of it, such as API gateway, CloudFront distro, Load balancer?

Comment: @Marcin I want to create an endpoint for public calling the api, e.g. "https://api.myapi.com/photo" etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments its seems that you want to use `https` for your endpoint. And probably this is the greatest thing to setup, assuming you already **own a domain**, e.g. `myapi.com`. If you don't have a domain, you have to buy one if you want custom url.

There are **several possibilities** to add `https`:

- Add `nginx` to your application as extra container, which will accept connections on port 443 and forward to your app on port 3030. `nginx` can be setup to use `https`. For that you need **valid, public ssl certificates** from a third party (e.g. letsencrypt). You could AWS ACM to get them, but for instance they only work with [nitro-enclave](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/nitro/nitro-enclaves/) instances. For instance you can use EIP and target Route53 record from your domain to the EIP.
- Front you instance with **Load Balancer** (LB). This is the **easiest** to setup, as you can get free SSL certs from ACM, and deploy them on the LB. Set your Route53 domain to point to LB url as an alias record.
- Setup **API Gateway** or **CloudFront** distro in-front of your EC2 instance. The issue is that connections between the API/CF and your instance will go over HTTP, unless you setup valid SSL certificates on your instance, like in the first possibility. You will also need EIP for the instance, or front it with LB, before using API Gateway or CloudFront.